Generate Caching SHA-2 Hash for user creation in Mysql 8.X
I want to create MySQL users, without having to deal with clear text passwords.
With the old mysql_native_password I would let the users to do a
SELECT CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('Sup3rS3cure_P4ssW0rd')))));
Then give me the resulting hash.
And then I would create a new user with
CREATE USER user@host IDENTIFIED WITH 'mysql_native_password' AS '*result_hash_goes_here...' and so on.
How do I achieve the same with the new caching_sha2_password authentication?
I know, that I can create an new user with
CREATE USER user@host IDENTIFIED WITH 'caching_sha2_password' AS 0xnewauthash
But how do I get the sha2-Password-Hash?

Why not give the user a random password and let them change the password after they have logged in into MySQL?

Sorry, for the late reply. That's because I also wrote a script that shares the hashes on different databases and the hashes are also stored in git.

You might want to check other questions like https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/77427/whats-the-algorithm-behind-mysqls-sha256-password-hashing-scheme

Thanks for that. I will try to make their perl script work for my purpose. If I find a solution for my problem, I will post it here.

I found a solution somewhere else : https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.mysql/issues/621#issuecomment-2051837825
It is possible to create valid hashes with this python script. I just need to add the ability to pass the password with command line args.
